# staff lounges Vs. staffroom

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What's the room of a medical staff only enter to it to rest and eat. Can I call it 'staffroom'? (I saw on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staffroom) that it's more for teachers' staff.

Comment: On the American medical TV drama "Grey's Anatomy" there's such a room called the "on-call room".

Comment: According to what I found this room has bed/s, and I'm asking about a room in any medical department not necessarily attended for sleep and doesn't have beds but may have chairs and sofa for a temporary sitting or having a coffee, lunch, or supper.

Comment: See also this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279451/what-is-a-room-a-company-provides-for-eating-food-called

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia page 'has issues'. It is incorrect in implying that staffrooms are only found in schools and colleges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer for the UK. The term staff room is commonly in use for a room provided for the medical and other staff to relax and gossip. It may also have food and drinks. The term doctors mess is also used, here is a link to one in the south of the UK http://www.sghdoctorsmess.co.uk/. I would expect that if such a facility were restricted to a specific grade of staff it would be called, for example, the consultants' mess as saying the consultants' staff room seem a bit tautological. (Consultants in the UK are the highest grade of registered medical practitioners. Whether in these more egalitarian times they still have separate facilities I do not know, it is some time since I worked in a hospital.)